# How do I wipe all personal information from my computer?

Tags: 10.10, system, cleanup

I'm awful with computers, I have ubuntu 10.10 and don't understand partioning etc.
I want to wipe my drive,everything EXCEPT the operating system (and auto boot obviously), without having to use a memory stick external hard drive etc, just leave ubuntu OS on but delete EVERYTHING else, is this possible?

Thank you so much in advance :)

PS. I have a format drive and format volumes option if this helps.
drive says something about master boot record, volumes says something about linux(0x83), which my computer once was or ubuntu 10.10 is? :)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 8069 MB, 8069677056 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 981 cylinders 
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x0008fa72 

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1 *             1         933     7490560   83  Linux Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             933         981      387073    5  Extended
```

Comment: We will need more information. Would you please open a terminal and post the result of "sudo fdisk -l"?

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 8069 MB, 8069677056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 981 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008fa72

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         933     7490560   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             933         981      387073    5  Extended

Comment: Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda5             933         981      387072   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: King, it seems you only have two partitions: one of the OS and one for swap. So you don't have to format any partition. Do you want to wipe or just delete the files?

Comment: pretty much delete all files, but i figure if i wipe, then it'll delete all virus' and malwear?

Comment: ps. whats swap?

Comment: The swap partition is where the OS "saves" the "files" when it is out of RAM memory. The difference between wipe and delete is that someone may recover the files (e.g. a txt file with passwords) that were deleted but not the files that were wiped. If you want to get ride of virus and malwares, you could use an antivirus, wouldn't you?

Comment: It sounds like the problem you are trying to recover from is spyware/malware. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to wipe all your information is to reinstall Ubuntu. It'll take about thirty minutes, and wipe everything that you've added. I think you'll be hard pressed to find a quicker and simpler method. If there's a reason you don't want to reinstall, comment here or edit your post.

Comment: Also this is the safest method, otherwise it's possible that you would miss something important.